# In Node, how do make a function run before the next command?

Tags: node.js

UPDATE: @jfriend00 below said what I'm attempting to do is impossible, which I would have known if I knew had asynchronicity worked. Which I still technically don't.  But they proved to me that I need to reverse the project out further to run my function sooner or redo it entirely at a higher level than the "scope" I was trying to run my function in. ‍♀️

---

This is kind of long but I'm at my wits end and need any kind of opinions from anyone. I always figure things out by using StackOverflow, I never use. So, just now, I'm desperate. And it seems to be something super commonly misunderstood but I have to ask about my specific situations since no solutions on the internet have helped me solve the problem.

I'm working on a mostly-open-source project called Cloudron (https://git.cloudron.io/cloudron/box/-/blob/master) and this is my first time working on a Node project. And I'm having the hardest time setting a variable and having it be available by the time I need it.

Having issues understanding asynchronous-ness in the context of this large a project that seems to use callbacks, which I also don't see how they will help because this variable needs to be set. I've read a ton of articles and a RIDICULOUS amount of stackoverflow problems / answers (and that's never failed me before). Stuff about Promises and callbacks and I try them and nothing I've experimented with actually waited for the variable to be set by my new function (I even wrote a setTimeout hoping that would just force it to wait and nothing really waited).

Anyway, to the meat of the actual problem - I added my new function to this project in src/docker.js:

```
function getVPNContainerName() {
    var containerIdVPN;
    gConnection.getNetwork('cloudron').inspect(function (error, bridge) {
        for (var id in bridge.Containers) {
            let v = inspect (id, function (error, container) {
                if(typeof container === "object") {
                    var environment = safe.query(container, 'Config.Env', null);
                    if (JSON.stringify(environment).includes("openvpnclient")) {
                        containerIdVPN = container.Name.substring(1);
                        debug ("INSIDE INSIDE FUNCTION:" + containerIdVPN);
                        return containerIdVPN;
                    }
                }
            });                 
        }
    });
}
```

And then I changed one line (https://git.cloudron.io/cloudron/box/-/blob/master/src/docker.js#L323) to run my function `containerOptions.HostConfig.NetworkMode = 'container:' + getVPNContainerName();` (which note, this is in the same file (docker.js), just inside a different function of that same file.

And because Node is asynchronous, It NEVER actually finishes the function I made (`getVPNContainerName()`) until after the program needs the functions value (thus the "containerOptions.HostConfig.NetworkMode" is undefined) - I can check this with the debug function (when things run when) and looking at the logs it's running after "NetworkMode" needs it.

I've tried putting the function all kinds of places. But it still runs after it's needed (I'm guessing because it's a intense function). But, I need the VPN container name to attach it to the NetworkMode it just *finishing* running *after* it's needed to return a value? I tried using Promises but that didn't work because I'm getting so many different syntax examples online. I know Cloudron is written in all these callback methodologies but I've only written in synchronous languages (namely PHP) so I don't know how to get the VPN name before it's needed, using that function (which works perfectly, and returns the exact variable needed).

Comment: Search for “how to use the result of an asynchronous function”. This includes callbacks, promises, and/or async/await and has been throughly discussed.

Comment: I'll search that exact term on here and Google. Thank you for your answer! I think I understand their concepts, but not their syntaxes.

Comment: For the function that needs your value, you need to call that function from within the `gConnection.getNetwork().inspect()` callback and pass it the value you need.  That's the ONLY way you it will know the proper timing because the timing of the `gConnection.getNetwork().inspect()` is completely unknown and it's non-blocking and asynchronous, so your other code has no idea when it's done and presumably is running BEFORE the value is set.  So, you have to call the other code from within that callback.

Comment: In this particular case, the getVPNContainerName function itself should be written in a way to expose the async operation out, so the caller can itself use the function asynchronously. I recommend exposing this as a promise (promises can wrap callbacks), which as the basis of await/async, instead of additional callbacks.

Comment: Hey, I'm having my a hard time wrapping my head around this so even having a stranger on the internet confirm that I'm just having asynchronous issues which I thought setTimeout would render irrelevant...but I'm starting to see that functions are exxecuting from the outside in. Really blows my mind, never seen this kind of coding method before.

Comment: For a better chance for us to offer you a specific answer with an actual code solution, please explain the exactly variable you want to use and show the function you want to use it in and where that fits into your code.

Comment: https://javascript.info/async-await — this page explains how to convert a callback into a promise, used as the result of an async function, which can be adapted here. The previous sections also cover basic promise ideas, which again: are the basis of async/await. This can make such code _much_ simpler — eg. `console.log(await myAsyncFunction())` — by automatically generating code to consume and create new promises.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay, that makes sense. I don't have a full example in my head. But this is my FIRST node edit of any kind so I'm just happy I've gotten this far (it's taken me two days just to write that function it's such a weird new language). I like contributing to open source projects and I'm pretty passionate about this one, I just need to let go of my PHP mindset I think.

Comment: Yes, asynchronous code in node.js/Javascript is a different beast.  It gets easier.  You will want to learn how to use only promise interfaces for asynchronous operations and then you can much more easily control the flow, timing and error handling.  For interfaces that don't offer a promise interface, you wrap it with one using `util.promisify()` so ALL your logic flow is using promises.  Then, you can also use `async` and `await` with the promise interfaces which also makes things easier.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've provided so far the link(s) to the EXACT single line of code I've changed (the function I added, and the project itself - a web app platform, I'm editing the backend) and the new function I added to "docker.js" in that project. And my variable is being set after it's needed and it just blew my mind when that happened. The problem is I can't just edit willy nilly since it's not my project so I'm trying to add my function that works and needs to pass a variable to https://git.cloudron.io/cloudron/box/-/blob/master/src/docker.js#L323 (changing what's there with my variable.

Comment: OK, I'm only now understanding what you were attempting to do.  You can't do what you're trying to do.  `GetVPNContainerName()` is asynchronous.  It cannot directly return your value.  The function itself will return LONG before the asynchronous value is available.  So, the one line change you're trying to make will never work.  It will take a larger change to integrate your asynchronously obtained value into the existing code.

Comment: Honestly, it's also a relief that you guys know it's possible. I just have to reverse engineer the project a little more. And learn the syntax..es of Promises (they seems to change from answer to answer but maybe there's more than one way.

Comment: @jfriend00 That was my thought. At least I know now, so I can go in another direction, reverse engineer the project further back. Thank you for linking into that for me. I've been at this for days non-stop because my brain couldn't let the problem go. Now I know there's likely another way, I feel good knowing that at least. Thank you. I knew it had something to do with asynchronicity but had no idea which direction to go in! You've helped me more than you know! ☺️

Comment: I could show you how to integrate your code into the existing code to replace the `NetworkMode` value, but frankly I don't understand what your replacement code is trying to accomplish.  You are inside of multiple callbacks and inside a loop and you're trying to return a value.  Please describe in words what your code is trying to do?  And, what should happen if it never finds an `openvpnclient` match?  What should happen if there is more than one match?  What should happen if either of your asynchronous calls gets an error?  None of this is clear to me from your code.

Comment: I see you also have an asynchronous call inside a loop.  That means you don't have control over the sequencing of those operations too.

Comment: Also, where does the `inspect` function come from that you call inside of `getVPNContainerName()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 Right now I'm trying to hardcode the possibility for Cloudron to have two of it's apps connected the the same Network (it's a Node-driven Docker dashboard) so that the second app can connect to the openvpnclient app (docker). And the only way to do that is right when creating the container, I specify the NetworkMode of the other container, which is the "name" / "id" of the openvpnclient that I coded (not in node ). So I have to search for that first. And that's why it takes so long. Maybe I can put my function super far back in the chain of the execution and use global variables?

Comment: @jfriend00 `inspect(id, callback)` is another function in the `docker.js` file that I use to dig into the containers data that Docker has running on the Cloudron network (which is why it uses a search of all the containers in the Cloudron Docker network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to integrate it.  I've tried to stay with the style of code already in this function (something you generally do when modifying other people's code).  Though, this whole thing really wants to be coded with promises where it would be soooo, so much easier to do control flow and error propagation.  Anyway, this will show you one possible way to integrate it:

```
function createSubcontainer(app, name, cmd, options, callback) {
    assert.strictEqual(typeof app, 'object');
    assert.strictEqual(typeof name, 'string');
    assert(!cmd || util.isArray(cmd));
    assert.strictEqual(typeof options, 'object');
    assert.strictEqual(typeof callback, 'function');

    let isAppContainer = !cmd; // non app-containers are like scheduler

    var manifest = app.manifest;
    var exposedPorts = {},
        dockerPortBindings = {};
    var domain = app.fqdn;

    const envPrefix = manifest.manifestVersion <= 1 ? '' : 'CLOUDRON_';

    let stdEnv = [
        'CLOUDRON=1',
        'CLOUDRON_PROXY_IP=172.18.0.1',
        `CLOUDRON_APP_HOSTNAME=${app.id}`,
        `${envPrefix}WEBADMIN_ORIGIN=${settings.adminOrigin()}`,
        `${envPrefix}API_ORIGIN=${settings.adminOrigin()}`,
        `${envPrefix}APP_ORIGIN=https://${domain}`,
        `${envPrefix}APP_DOMAIN=${domain}`
    ];

    // docker portBindings requires ports to be exposed
    exposedPorts[manifest.httpPort + '/tcp'] = {};

    dockerPortBindings[manifest.httpPort + '/tcp'] = [{ HostIp: '127.0.0.1', HostPort: app.httpPort + '' }];

    var portEnv = [];
    for (let portName in app.portBindings) {
        const hostPort = app.portBindings[portName];
        const portType = (manifest.tcpPorts && portName in manifest.tcpPorts) ? 'tcp' : 'udp';
        const ports = portType == 'tcp' ? manifest.tcpPorts : manifest.udpPorts;

        var containerPort = ports[portName].containerPort || hostPort;

        exposedPorts[`${containerPort}/${portType}`] = {};
        portEnv.push(`${portName}=${hostPort}`);

        dockerPortBindings[`${containerPort}/${portType}`] = [{ HostIp: '0.0.0.0', HostPort: hostPort + '' }];
    }

    let appEnv = [];
    Object.keys(app.env).forEach(function(name) { appEnv.push(`${name}=${app.env[name]}`); });

    // first check db record, then manifest
    var memoryLimit = app.memoryLimit || manifest.memoryLimit || 0;

    if (memoryLimit === -1) { // unrestricted
        memoryLimit = 0;
    } else if (memoryLimit === 0 || memoryLimit < constants.DEFAULT_MEMORY_LIMIT) { // ensure we never go below minimum (in case we change the default)
        memoryLimit = constants.DEFAULT_MEMORY_LIMIT;
    }

    // give scheduler tasks twice the memory limit since background jobs take more memory
    // if required, we can make this a manifest and runtime argument later
    if (!isAppContainer) memoryLimit *= 2;

    addons.getEnvironment(app, function(error, addonEnv) {
        if (error) return callback(error);

        let containerOptions = {
            name: name, // for referencing containers
            Tty: isAppContainer,
            Image: app.manifest.dockerImage,
            Cmd: (isAppContainer && app.debugMode && app.debugMode.cmd) ? app.debugMode.cmd : cmd,
            Env: stdEnv.concat(addonEnv).concat(portEnv).concat(appEnv),
            ExposedPorts: isAppContainer ? exposedPorts : {},
            Volumes: { // see also ReadonlyRootfs
                '/tmp': {},
                '/run': {}
            },
            Labels: {
                'fqdn': app.fqdn,
                'appId': app.id,
                'isSubcontainer': String(!isAppContainer),
                'isCloudronManaged': String(true)
            },
            HostConfig: {
                Mounts: addons.getMountsSync(app, app.manifest.addons),
                Binds: getBindsSync(app), // ideally, we have to use 'Mounts' but we have to create volumes then
                LogConfig: {
                    Type: 'syslog',
                    Config: {
                        'tag': app.id,
                        'syslog-address': 'udp://127.0.0.1:2514', // see apps.js:validatePortBindings()
                        'syslog-format': 'rfc5424'
                    }
                },
                Memory: memoryLimit / 2,
                MemorySwap: memoryLimit, // Memory + Swap
                PortBindings: isAppContainer ? dockerPortBindings : {},
                PublishAllPorts: false,
                ReadonlyRootfs: app.debugMode ? !!app.debugMode.readonlyRootfs : true,
                RestartPolicy: {
                    'Name': isAppContainer ? 'unless-stopped' : 'no',
                    'MaximumRetryCount': 0
                },
                CpuShares: app.cpuShares,
                VolumesFrom: isAppContainer ? null : [app.containerId + ':rw'],
                SecurityOpt: ['apparmor=docker-cloudron-app'],
                CapAdd: [],
                CapDrop: []
            }
        };

        // do no set hostname of containers to location as it might conflict with addons names. for example, an app installed in mail
        // location may not reach mail container anymore by DNS. We cannot set hostname to fqdn either as that sets up the dns
        // name to look up the internal docker ip. this makes curl from within container fail
        // Note that Hostname has no effect on DNS. We have to use the --net-alias for dns.
        // Hostname cannot be set with container NetworkMode. Subcontainers run is the network space of the app container
        // This is done to prevent lots of up/down events and iptables locking
        if (isAppContainer) {
            containerOptions.Hostname = app.id;
            containerOptions.HostConfig.NetworkMode = 'cloudron'; // user defined bridge network
            containerOptions.HostConfig.Dns = ['172.18.0.1']; // use internal dns
            containerOptions.HostConfig.DnsSearch = ['.']; // use internal dns

            containerOptions.NetworkingConfig = {
                EndpointsConfig: {
                    cloudron: {
                        Aliases: [name] // adds hostname entry with container name
                    }
                }
            };
            finish();
        } else {
            getVPNContainerName(function(err, val) {
                if (err) {
                    // you need to pick some error here - this error is just copied from some other code in this functionj
                    callback(new BoxError(BoxError.ALREADY_EXISTS, error));
                } else {
                    containerOptions.HostConfig.NetworkMode = val;
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }

        // asynchronous function, calls callback(err, val) when it's complete
        function getVPNContainerName(callback) {
            var containerIdVPN;
            var done = false;
            gConnection.getNetwork('cloudron').inspect(function(error, bridge) {
                if (error) {
                    callback(error);
                    return;
                }
                for (var id in bridge.Containers) {
                    // problem with sequencing of this async operation inside of for loop
                    let v = inspect(id, function(error, container) {
                        if (error) {
                            // log error and skip
                            debug(error);
                            return;
                        }
                        if (typeof container === "object") {
                            var environment = safe.query(container, 'Config.Env', null);
                            if (JSON.stringify(environment).includes("openvpnclient")) {
                                containerIdVPN = container.Name.substring(1);
                                debug("INSIDE INSIDE FUNCTION:" + containerIdVPN);
                                if (!done) {
                                    done = true;
                                    callback(null, containerIdVPN);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (!done) {
                    // use default value
                    callback(null, `container:${app.containerId}`);
                }
            });
        }

        function finish() {

            var capabilities = manifest.capabilities || [];

            // https://docs-stage.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities
            if (capabilities.includes('net_admin')) containerOptions.HostConfig.CapAdd.push('NET_ADMIN', 'NET_RAW');
            if (capabilities.includes('mlock')) containerOptions.HostConfig.CapAdd.push('IPC_LOCK'); // mlock prevents swapping
            if (!capabilities.includes('ping')) containerOptions.HostConfig.CapDrop.push('NET_RAW'); // NET_RAW is included by default by Docker

            if (capabilities.includes('vaapi') && safe.fs.existsSync('/dev/dri')) {
                containerOptions.HostConfig.Devices = [
                    { PathOnHost: '/dev/dri', PathInContainer: '/dev/dri', CgroupPermissions: 'rwm' }
                ];
            }

            containerOptions = _.extend(containerOptions, options);

            gConnection.createContainer(containerOptions, function(error, container) {
                if (error && error.statusCode === 409) return callback(new BoxError(BoxError.ALREADY_EXISTS, error));
                if (error) return callback(new BoxError(BoxError.DOCKER_ERROR, error));

                callback(null, container);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Some notes:

1. Your `for` loop is actually running a bunch of `inspect()` calls in parallel.  Since it was not clear whether you wanted to run them in parallel or in sequence, this code just accepts the first one that finishes and matches the `openvpnclient` test and then sets a flag to ignore any others as they finish.
2. It's not clear what you want to set the value to, if there are no `openvpnclient` matches.  I coded it to set the value that the code did before your code was added.
3. If you want to sequence the calls to inspect rather than run them all in parallel, then I'd need to know if it's OK to use `async/await` in this code or not.  It's a fairly old style of code (using `var`, for example) and only plain callbacks so that wasn't clear to me if it can use modern syntax or not.

Comment: You made all the assumptions correctly. Their can only be **one** VPN client (for now), and if it exists, it attaches to the network mode, otherwise things stay as normal just like you made them. 

I'm so blown away by how someone who knows how this works can accomplish what was taking me days.

Note: at the top of the docker.js file, it says requires 'async', it works if I add it to my function too (no errors) - but I didn't know where to go from there.

Comment: @JoelS - Don't add `async` to your function with this implementation as it does nothing useful and just adds a little extra overhead.  You would only do that if you were using `await` with asynchronous operations that return promises.  You don't currently have that.

Comment: This is the first open source project I've needed to make changes to and I've never touched anything aside from PHP. So...throwing the end of the function into `finish()` and then using a callback for the function I wrote allow for this to happen. I'm just about to try it, I'm so excited! THANK YOUUUU!

Comment: Okay, I didn't think so, the original `box` of that project was made in 2018. So, it uses all callback everywhere.

Comment: I'm definitely further than I was now, thank you for confirming with me that I need to use callback mentality why REing this app. Giving me an example was perfect. There are a host of issues I realize now too so I'll be changing the code to make it make more sense for the purposes of the project!

Comment: @JoelS - If this helped you figure things out, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.

Comment: With some minor adjustments, it worked! Wow, I realize how inefficient it is, but I needed this exact example to show me how all of these callback things work. You're a hero today!

Comment: I tried to upvote, but it wouldn't let me, never saw the checkmark (but clicked it now). Thanks for helping me figure this out. I still can't believe you did it, knowing so little of the project as a whole. Mind blown. ☺️

Comment: Not only did your answer help me figure this out, it helped me turn my code into a  working proof of concept to the **actual** developers who might be able to get those values in more efficient ways. 

If you hadn't have helped me I'd still be sitting here trying to use Promises and getting nowhere. I realize now this project I'm developing uses callbacks and I understand the execution flow now (and understand how you "blocked" it until my variable was returned). 

I read 20 blog posts and 30 StackOver questions about how to work with asynchronicity and I didn't get it till your answer.

Comment: @Lonk - Cool.  Glad that helped you understand it.

Comment: You inspired me to want to help other people so I've been answering questions in my speciality (PHP, Wordpress) and I got enough reputation points to upvote your answer so I did that. Thanks again. I don't think words can really express how grateful I am to you.